# Listbox Database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, listbox

Okay, so for a project I'm not allowed to use Datagridview and instead I'll have to use a Listbox to display data from a database when it is searched for. I'll link my code below, could anyone please tell me how I can change this code to suit a listbox. I'm a noob to programming so if I've made any obvious mistakes please forgive me

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmUserList

```
Private Sub btnClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub Load_Record()
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty

    'try catch block is used to catch the error
    Try
        'get connection string declared in the Module1.vb and assing it to conn variable
        conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sSQL = "SELECT user_id,  last_name + ', ' + first_name + ' ' + mid_name as name FROM users where last_name + ', ' + first_name + ' ' + mid_name like '%" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "%' or [first_name] = '" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "'"

        cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)

        Me.dtgResult.DataSource = dt
        If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("No record found!")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Load_Record()
End Sub

Private Sub dtgResult_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dtgResult.DoubleClick
    If Me.dtgResult.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim frm As New frmMarkSeat
        frm.txtFname.Tag = Me.dtgResult.Item(0, Me.dtgResult.CurrentRow.Index).Value
        frm.ShowDialog()
        frm = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try using `SQLDataReader`: (untested code, just wrote out of hand).

```
'start here
conn.Connection.Open()
Dim sqlDR As SqlDataReader
Dim colValue As String

 sqlDR = conn.ExecuteReader
 While sqlDR.Read
   colValue = (sqlDR.GetValue(0)).ToString
   ItemlistBox.Items.Add(colValue)
   ItemlistBox.Sorted = True
 End While

 conn.Connection.Close()
```

Or you can keep using your current objects, with additional object `DataSet` and populate the listbox.

```
Dim dtset As New DataSet
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

da.Fill(dtset)
ItemListBox.DataSource = dtset
ItemListBox.DisplayMember = "ColName"
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: System.Data.DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor